# variable-sized object may not be initialized - C error

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a code, but it can't build. I want to read 3 differents names up to 40 characters each, save in one vector and print it. I need to do it using function. I'm getting "Variable-sized object may not be initialized" for line 15. I believe that I could get this error if the vector's size was not defined. I've already tried to define it using constants (NOMESQUAN and NOMESTAM) and in the declaration (nomes[3][41]), but I get the same error everytime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOMESQUAN 3
#define NOMESTAM 41

int lenomes(int i);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char nomes[NOMESQUAN][NOMESTAM];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
         char nomes[i][NOMESTAM] = lenomes(i); /*LINE 15*/
    }

}

int lenomes(int i){
    char nome[NOMESTAM];

    printf("Digite o nome %d", i);
    gets(nome);

    return nome;
}
```

Comment: 'return nome;' - nope.  You cannot do that.

Comment: Your code has multiple problems, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to `char` in `lenomes` which has `int` as a return type. You're declaring `nomes` two times (one in the beginning of `main` and the second is in the loop).

Comment: There are no `vector` or vector-like structures here, removed tag. It appears you might mean "array" instead?

Comment: `char nomes[i][NOMESTAM] = ...`  is a variable definition. You might want to remove the `char`. This however will reveal other issues.

Comment: Yes, I mean array! Sorry, english mistake D:

Comment: I just did it. Thanks ForceBru and alk.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function `lenomes` contains nonsense code and will not compile. You cannot return an array from a function. And you haven't declared the function to return an array either, you have declared it to return an `int`. How this makes sense, you tell me.

---

> char nomes[NOMESQUAN][NOMESTAM];

Here you declare an array, but then inside the loop you declare another array `char nomes[i][NOMESTAM]` again, but this time as a variable-length array (since `i` is a run-time variable). Such arrays cannot be initialized, since it only makes sense for them to get values in run-time.

---

To sum it up, when programming you can't just take a chance at the language syntax, you actually have to know what every single line you write does.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOMESQUAN 3
#define NOMESTAM 41

void lenomes (int i, char nomes[i][NOMESTAM]);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char nomes[NOMESQUAN][NOMESTAM];

    for(i=0; i<NOMESQUAN; i++){
         lenomes(i, nomes);
    }

}

void lenomes (int i, char nomes[i][NOMESTAM]) {
    printf("Digite o nome %d", i);
    gets(nome[i]);
}
```

Comment: _However_, note that the function `gets` has been removed from the C language. It was noted that the function is intrinsically dangerous to use around 25 years ago, it was therefore made obsolete 17 years ago and completely removed 5 years ago. So whoever taught you to use it is not a good source for leaning C programming, their knowledge is completely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
char nomes[i][NOMESTAM] = lenomes(i); /*LINE 15*/
```

there is defined a variable length array that is attempted to initialize. First of all VLA may not be initialized and more over the initialization in any case is incorrect.

Function `lenomes` is also invalid.

int lenomes(int i){
    char nome[NOMESTAM];

```
printf("Digite o nome %d", i);
gets(nome);

return nome;
```

}

It tries to return a pointer converted to type int that has the address of the first element of a local array that will be destroyed after exiting the function.

Take into account that function `gets` is not supported any more by the C Standard because it is unsafe.

You need something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOMESQUAN 3
#define NOMESTAM 41

char * lenomes( char *nome, size_t n );

int main( void )
{
    size_t i;
    char nomes[NOMESQUAN][NOMESTAM];

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof( nomes ) / sizeof( *nomes ); i++ )
    {
         lenomes( nomes[i], sizeof( nomes[i] ) );
    }
}

char * lenomes( char *nome, size_t n )
{
    char *p;

    printf( "Digite o nome " );
    p = fgets( nome, n, stdin );

    if ( p ) p[strcspn( p, "\n" )] = '\0'; 

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of comments that showed the problems in your code, here is a possible implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* io functions MUST be declared */

#define NOMESQUAN 3
#define NOMESTAM 41

/* pass a buffer and a length to io routine */
char *lenomes(int i, char *buf, int sz);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char nomes[NOMESQUAN][NOMESTAM];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
         lenomes(i, nomes[i], NOMESTAM); /*LINE 15*/
    }

}

char* lenomes(int i, char *nome, int sz){

    printf("Digite o nome %d", i);
    return fgets(nome, sz, stdin);  /* NEVER use gets */
}
```